# nginx complaining that there is "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive on port 80

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, wordpress

When trying to restart nginx, I get the error `nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive`. I am using SSL, but the error occurs at line 54 of my site's nginx config file- where the second `server {` is, with the purpose to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. My config file is as follows, with example.com as replacement for my actual domain name.

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
#

# Default server configuration
#

server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /var/www/default/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/default/key.pem;

        root /var/www/default;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ { log_not_found off; }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT  $realpath_root;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com;
}
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

I am a bit of a noob at this, so sorry if I get anything wrong, and I'll gladly add details as requested. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any more to your config file? That doesn't look like 54 lines. It might also be worth checking that the certificate and key paths are both correct and the files are readable by the user nginx runs as.

Comment: What is the output of `nginx -t` exactly?

Comment: @Ladadadada Oops, sorry about that, didn't include all the commented stuff, will edit my comment.

Comment: @tilleyc 
nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:54
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed